# get the first occurrence partitioned by a column sorted by another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['1','1','1','2','2'],
                   "LINE":['1','3','2','1','2'],
                   "TYPE":['0','1','1','1','0']})
# print results
print(df.head())

# a function to label the first type 1 for each ID sorted by line
# currently it only filters to type 1
def label (row):
    if row.TYPE == '1' :
        return True

# add the label in the dataframe
df['label'] = df.apply (lambda row: label(row), axis=1)

# print results
print(df.head())
```

I would like to get the first occurrence of `TYPE == 1` for each unique `ID` sorted by `LINE`. End results should be:

```
  ID LINE TYPE label
0  1    1    0  None
1  1    3    1  None
2  1    2    1  True
3  2    1    1  True
4  2    2    0  None
```

I am using a sample in this question, but I am dealing with 3 million data rows in reality and want to know the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `query` to filter the `TYPE == 1`, `sort_values` to sort `LINE` and finally `GroupBy.head` to get the first occurence:

```
s = df.query('TYPE == "1"').sort_values('LINE').groupby('ID')['TYPE'].head(1)
df['label'] = df.index.isin(s.index)
```

Or with `drop_duplicates`, which should be more efficient:

```
s = df.query('TYPE == "1"').sort_values('LINE').drop_duplicates('ID')
df['label'] = df.index.isin(s.index)
```

```
  ID LINE TYPE  label
0  1    1    0  False
1  1    3    1  False
2  1    2    1   True
3  2    1    1   True
4  2    2    0  False
```

Comment: Normally, `drop_duplicates` will be faster than `groupby().head(1)`.